# VIsual Studio: Deleting SUO file causes vs2013 to hang?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, suo

Visual Studio 2013 was acting up - it would take > 20 minutes to compile.

I decided to try and help myself by deleting the SUO file thinking that may be a good first step.

Here is the thing, when I delete the file VS hangs at "loading solution".  Put it back - at least the project opens (but still takes forever to compile).

From all I know this file should just regenerate - what gives?

Comment: Have you tried to disable your network adapter just for the loading part.. sometimes it may solve the issue...

Comment: I figured this out on my own a few minutes ago, but your suggestion was actually spot on so I am going to accept it.  For benefit of the community in my .proj file there were "hints" to a location that was not accessible and therefore causing an issue.   I opened the file in notepad and removed them.  Obviously this is a best practice issue and not a bug... Good guess by the way - your figured it out before senior escalation at MSFT did.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer for others, please mark it as a solution and if you may, vote up for the educated guess :)

Comment: sadly I cannot vote up yet but will accept..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to disable your network adapter. In some cases the issue comes from vs2013 trying to connect with your Microsoft username on load.

I hope it address your issue.